# .htaccess rewrite rules to set a subdirectory as a root directory do not apply no Firefox browser

Tags: .htaccess, firefox, url-rewriting

I have this in my root .htaccess file at /var/www/html

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example/$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I visit [localhost](http://localhost) in Chrome Browser, the example site opens but in Firefox Browser default apache success page opens.

Is there some mistake in the Rewrite Rules or it is a setting problem in Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I got it figured out:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [L]
```

This code in .htaccess works well to serve your **subdir** at **localhost**, that means,http://localhost/subdir is now equivalent to http://localhost